Can the height of the scorll bar be set vertically?
I am trying to create a custom vertical scrollbar using the following LESS code.
The goal is to style the scrollbar such that:

The scrollbar's height dynamically occupies 80% of the container's height.
The container has a fixed height of 361px.

Here's the context of my code for the container:
.wrap-container-chart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 361px;
  overflow: auto; 
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  .scrollbar-style-xy();

  .container-chart {
    min-width: 120%;
    min-height: 120% !important;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

And here is the LESS code for the custom scrollbar:
.scrollbar-style-xy() {
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF9900 0%, #FBC334 100%);
    border-radius: 40px;
    width: 5px; 
    height: 5px; 
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgba(233, 233, 233, 1);
    border-radius: 40px;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical {
    background: rgba(233, 233, 233, 1);
    border-radius: 40px;
    height: 80%;
  }
}

Problem:
The scrollbar's height doesn't seem to adjust dynamically to 80% of the container height. Instead, it appears full height or behaves differently depending on the browser.
Question:
How can I modify this code to ensure the vertical scrollbar always dynamically takes 80% of the container's height? Are there better approaches or fixes for this issue?
Thank you for your guidance!
